# Error encountered with migration to cpanel

Tags: cpanel, plesk

I was running my webserver on Plesk platform before moving to `CPanel` due to my perceived perception of Plesk's over-sensibility to threats to security.

After the migration, my site runs quite alright but a sister site that has my IP in its `A record`s couldn't connect through me anymore. It only brings a default website CGI page. Please, I need help.

Comment: Looks like you have missing virtualhost entry in httd.conf. Check /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf. You also try to rebuild your httpd.conf via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created your second site on your cPanel server ? If yes, then there is an issues with the IP, Please check your domain IP and httpd configuration file on cPanel server and try update that IP in  your DNS zone which are you using on cPanel server. Most of the time this type of issues occur due to wrong IP.

Answer (score 0):

All i did was to create a wildcard subdomain which was attached to the subdomain already created on the other server i was trying to point to. That did the magic. Sorry my response seems belated.